# .htaccess redirect not working?

Tags: .htaccess

.htaccess file is not working... 
I don't know Why ??
Help me out here is my code
.htaccess file

```
   RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewrite
Rule  ^(.*)$ index.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and php file.

```
 if (isset($_GET['usernamess']) === true && empty($_GET['usernamess']) === false) {
    $usernamess = $_GET['usernamess'];
echo $usernamess;
}else {
header('index.php');
}
```

Comment: You will need to write "RewriteRule" in 1 line, not in 2 lines, and you use the variable 'name' and 'usernamess'. They should be the same I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your Root/.htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?name=([^\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?name=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

and name and usernamess should be the same

Comment: okay thank you but i tried everything like

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?usernamess=([^\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?usernamess=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

and 

if (isset($_GET['usernamess']) === true && empty($_GET['usernamess']) === false) {
    $usernamess = $_GET['usernamess'];
echo $usernamess;
}else {
header('index.php');
}

but no use... :(

Comment: for your problem **you want to redirect `xxx.aa/index.php?name=alex` to `xxx.aa/1`**

Comment: Do you have rewrite_module activated? you should allow .htaccess files to be used

Comment: Yes My rewrite_module is activated AllowOverride All is also okay..
but still not working.. :( :( :(